# CSS Keyframes animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I need some help with the animations in CSS. Say I have following animation

```
from {left: 0; opacity: 1}
to {left: 20%; opacity: 0.8}
```

This works when I hover over it, however when I do mouseleave I want my animation to go in reverse direction i.e first return opacity to 1 and only then make left to 0. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use use:

```
[selector]:not(:focus) {
    /* animation code */
}
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vvK5zIsYqEFOKoqqdZQM?p=preview)

```css
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
@keyframes example1 {
    from {background-color: yellow;}
    to {background-color: red;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
    from {background-color: yellow;}
    to {background-color: red;}
}
/* The element to apply the animation to */
input {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    
    background-color: red;
    
}
input:focus{
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
input:not(:focus){
  -webkit-animation-name: example1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example1;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you need?

```
from:not(:focus) {
    left: 0; opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: and what's "to" should look like?